# Is Using bootstrap professional work or not?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, themes

Today many of web designers use bootstrap. Is it professional to build website based on bootstrap and charging money from the client as the website is their own work. Its look unfair for the client who doesn't know about website themes or bootstrap. Should I clear it first if they want bootstrap or any theme for faster work or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think bootstrap is more or less professional than alternatives.

You should certainly clear it with your client.  Make it clear to them what the advantages and disadvantages are with using a framework.  Tell them if it'll constrain their choices in any way and get their buy in.

Comment: I think i should charge less if i use bootstrap and don't tell about it to the client. Because client have some weird thinking about shortcuts. They will think that they can build website with bootstrap on his own. :P

Comment: Sounds devious and underhanded to me.  If they're smart enough to do it with bootstrap, why do they need you?  I hope you're bringing more value than that.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should charge the client for every piece of work that you do for them. After all, you are selling your time and energy. If the client feels like he/she shouldn't pay, they can always make the web site on their own using Bootstrap or whatever.
For me it's the same thing as installing Windows on someone's computer. It's incredibly easy and everyone can learn to do it if they are willing. But if they are lazy enough, they can and should be charged for the service that you provide.

Comment: okay, so you want to say that you will charge the client by telling him that the whole work of website is your own work???

Comment: I spent my time learning how to use Bootstrap. I downloaded the required files, and made a functional web site using them. THAT is the work that I will charge for.
If the client asks me about technology that I've used, I will tell them. Otherwise, the only thing they should worry about is whether I will or will not deliver the project.